# SQL Server ODBC "TCP Provider: Error code 0x274C"

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I got the following error from the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server:

```
[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x274C (10060) (SQLExecDirectW)
```

I can tell from [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/appendix-a-odbc-error-codes) on the SQLSTATE values for ODBC that the `08S01` indicates that the issue was a "communication link failure", but I'm having trouble finding documentation that indicates the meaning of `TCP Provider: Error code 0x274C` and so I don't know whether this gives more specific information about the failure.

What does the `0x274C` error code mean?

Comment: Error code 0x274C (10060),  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-10060-database-engine-error

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that 10060 was decimal for 0x274C, so I didn't realize those were the same error code.  Strange that they print it in hexadecimal here if it's formatted as decimal everywhere else.

Comment: If you put this in an answer then I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Error code 0x274C (10060)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-10060-database-engine-error)

> **Explanation**
>
> The SQL Server client cannot connect to the server. This error could
> occur because either the firewall on the server has refused the
> connection or the server is not configured to accept remote
> connections.

Comment: Thanks. However, I am getting reports of this error on a server where the firewall is properly open to allow the remote host, and the SQL Server is configured to accept remote connections. In this case, the issue occurrence is sporadic and depends on the time of day (roughly between 4 am and 8 am). Just adding this comment to give further context - I think something else is going on during those times that may be unrelated to firewall access or remote connection settings, but is somehow being reported with that error?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same connection issue. I was able to connect to a remote MSSQL server using DB Weaver but facing issues when trying to connect using file. If you're using multiple php versions, please remove all unwanted versions.

```
sudo apt-get purge php5.*
sudo apt-get purge php5.6  #specific version
```

restart apache2 or nginix server `php sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`